# Problem with random object from an array in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

So I have this issue. I can't print in

random "content" from an array.
Heres link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evyfzd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

My array looks like this:

```
[ { id: '1', category: 'comedy', content: 'Millers' },
    { id: '2', category: 'horror', content: 'Sinister' }]
```

and my code from Visual is on stackblitz.

Comment: Please provide all the relevant content as part of the question, use the [edit] functionality to create a minimal viable reproducible example. The code in question should be part of the question, and not linked to an outside source (if the outside source becomes obsolete, so too would the question)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood. You are trying to print a value in the array randomly.
Since your value array only consists of 2 object your `Math.random` function needed to be fixed properly. Here's the working code :

**app.component.html :**

```
<div class="container">
  <p>{{ randomValue.content }}</p>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public randomValue: any;
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  public movies: any = [
    { id: '1', category: 'comedy', content: 'Millers' },
    { id: '2', category: 'horror', content: 'Sinister' }
  ];

  constructor(private AppService: AppService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData();
  }
  loadData() {
    let ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0) + 0);
    this.randomValue = this.movies[ran];
    console.log(ran);
    console.log(this.movies[ran]);
  }
}
```

**Please find the working sample stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zgy1yu?file=src/app/app.component.ts).**